# YUI2 datatable inside tab

Tags: datatable, yui

I have a datatable configured as below

```
function handleTabChange(e){    
var errDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource("/webapp/somecontroller");
    errDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSON;
    errDataSource.responseSchema = { 
              fields: [
                        "id","name","err_msg","err_sugg","created_at","created_by","rev"
                       ] 
              };
    var errColDef = [ 
                   {key:"error_id", sortable:true}, 
                    {key:"created_at", formatter:YAHOO.widget.DataTable.formatDate, sortable:true, sortOptions:{defaultDir:YAHOO.widget.DataTable.CLASS_DESC}}, 
                    {key:"name",  sortable:true}, 
                    {key:"rev",  sortable:true}, 
                    {key:"err_msg"}, 
                    {key:"err_sugg" }, 
                    {key:"created_by"} 
                ]; 
    var errorDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.Datatable("errorDataTable",errColDef, errDataSource,{scrollable:true,width:"100%"});
    errorDataTable.render();
}
```

In my tab where I want to populate this datatable I add the following line

```
tab3.addListener('click', handleTabChange);
```

When I debug this , I can see that the control flows through

> handleTabChange

but my network  shows no calls being made by the datasource.

Can you pleae hlep me if I am integrating the datatable to the tab view correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a complete answer but I haven't been using YUI2 for quite some time now. This is what I recall, I hope it helps.  There was an issue when creating a DataTable in a hidden container, specially a scrolling DataTable when it needs to do a lot of size calculations to sync the headers to the content.   In some browsers, trying to read the width or height of invisible elements causes an error.  It is quite possible that if you run your code in a debugger with the 'break on error' option on, you will see some error happening.  This prevents the DataTable from completing the initialization and, thus, it never reaches the part when it fetches the data.

I didn't remember the name, but browsing through the API docs I found [onShow()](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.DataTable.html#method_onShow) which was meant to fix this.

Also, listening to a click on the tab does not guarantee that the panel for the tab is visible.  You should listen to the `activeTabChange`  on the TabView which fires after the tab has become visible.

Sorry if I can't be of much help, it's been a while. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used YUI2 in a while (and I strongly recommend you not to write any new code with YUI2 and switch to YUI3 for new stuff), but it looks like you're missing the `initialRequest` option or to call `sendRequest` on the DataSource.

The [DataTable Control: JSON Data Over XHR](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_xhrjson.html) example shows how to use of `initialRequest` and `sendRequest`.